# Nested enumerate list, Page breaks

Tags: lists, page-breaking, enumerate, nesting

I am currently writing a multiple choice exam: There is a enumerated list for the question number and then a nested list for the choices within each multiple choice question:
1. Question 1
    a)
    b)
    c)
    d)
2. Question 2
    a)
    b)
    c)
    d) ...
With a long list of questions, it is common that the choices to a particular question become separated between pages. The most straightforward way to fix this problem is to just write `\newpage` where ever the break occurs. I am wondering if there is a better way? Is it possible to change (or create a new) envirement that always groups the choices so that they never get separated between pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to wrap your list inside a `minipage` (`minipage`s don't admit page breaks):

```
\documentclass{exam}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{questions}
\question
One of these things is not like the others; one of these things is not
the same. Which one is different?
\begin{choices}
\choice John
\choice Paul
\choice George
\choice Ringo
\choice Socrates
\end{choices}
\end{questions}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

And, of course, you could define a new environment to alleviate the job:

```
\documentclass{exam}

\newenvironment{nbchoices}[1]
  {\par\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\begin{questions}\question#1\begin{choices}}
  {\end{choices}\end{questions}\end{minipage}\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{nbchoices}{One of these things is not like the others; one of these things is not
the same. Which one is different?}
\choice John
\choice Paul
\choice George
\choice Ringo
\choice Socrates
\end{nbchoices}

\end{document}
```

Using `article` and standard `enumerate` environments, the same idea applies:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{nbchoices}[1]
  {\item#1\par\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\begin{enumerate}}
  {\end{enumerate}\end{minipage}\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\begin{nbchoices}{One of these things is not like the others; one of these things is not
the same. Which one is different?}
\item John
\item Paul
\item George
\item Ringo
\item Socrates
\end{nbchoices}
\begin{nbchoices}{One of these things is not like the others; one of these things is not
the same. Which one is different?}
\item John
\item Paul
\item George
\item Ringo
\item Socrates
\end{nbchoices}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

No page breaks won't occur in between choices.

Comment: Ideally I would like to use the article documentclass since exams will consist of more than just multiple choice questions. I am not sure that minipage will work: I want page breaks to occur when the page fills with questions, just not in between choices.

Comment: @richtera: see my updated answer.

Comment: I guess there is still one problem...the question can get separated from the choices. For example the question can be on page 4, but all the choices are on page 5.

Comment: I moved the minipage command and that fixed it.

Comment: @richtera: yes, that's what was needed.