# Page breaks with `enumerate` and `tabular`

Tags: tables, lists, page-breaking, enumerate, tufte

I'm making a handout with blanks that I want students to fill in, like so:

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Caleb

    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
        \begin{fullwidth}
            \noindent \begin{tabular}{p{6in}}
                \dotfill\\\dotfill\\\dotfill
            \end{tabular}


        \end{fullwidth}

    \item Nathan

    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
        \begin{fullwidth}
            \noindent \begin{tabular}{p{6in}}
                \dotfill\\\dotfill\\\dotfill
            \end{tabular}


        \end{fullwidth}

    \item Ava

    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
        \begin{fullwidth}
            \noindent \begin{tabular}{p{6in}}
                \dotfill\\\dotfill\\\dotfill
            \end{tabular}


        \end{fullwidth}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Which works well enough, but sometimes the page breaks are a problem, like so:
[image]

Is there a way to keep the enumerated `item` and the dotted lines together on the same page, other than a manual `\newpage`? I did see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51318/nested-enumerate-list-page-breaks), which suggests `minipage`, but that seems like a different situation.

NB: Technically the code above isn't a MWE, because it doesn't generate exactly what you see in the image, but I figured it was close enough for this purpose. If it isn't, let me know and I'll fix it.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the minipage solution? It would be fine here.

Comment: it would have been more useful to adjust your example so that it was an example of the problem (ie had a bad page break) so people can test answers)

Comment: Is there any documentation on fullwidth?  I can't find it in any KOMA documentation, nor can I find a tufte manual (only examples).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Duly noted. I'll know next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `samepage` environment: intended for exactly this situation.

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Caleb

    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
        \begin{fullwidth}
            \noindent \begin{tabular}{p{6in}}
                \dotfill\\\dotfill\\\dotfill
            \end{tabular}


        \end{fullwidth}
\begin{samepage}
    \item Nathan

    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
        \begin{fullwidth}
            \noindent \begin{tabular}{p{6in}}
                \dotfill\\\dotfill\\\dotfill
            \end{tabular}


        \end{fullwidth}
\end{samepage}

    \item Ava

    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
        \begin{fullwidth}
            \noindent \begin{tabular}{p{6in}}
                \dotfill\\\dotfill\\\dotfill
            \end{tabular}


        \end{fullwidth}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I put the dotted lines into a savebox so I could measure them, but it is also faster this way.  I used `\rlap` instead of `fullwidth`, based on what documentation i could find.  The terminating `\par` (blank line) seems to have no affect (I was worried about the fact that `\item` includes a `\par`).

It should be noted that `\itemsep` and `\parsep` change depending on the environment.

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{needspace}

\newsavebox{\dottedlines}
\savebox{\dottedlines}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
  \begin{tabular}{p{6in}}
    \dotfill\\
    \dotfill\\ 
    \dotfill
  \end{tabular}%
}
\newlength{\itemsize}


\begin{document}
\rule{1pt}{22\baselineskip}% Ava will fit with 21
\begin{enumerate}
    \setlength{\itemsize}{\dimexpr \itemsep+\baselineskip+\parsep+\ht\dottedlines+\dp\dottedlines}
    \needspace{\itemsize}
    \item Caleb

    \noindent\rlap{\usebox{\dottedlines}}

    \needspace{\itemsize}
    \item Nathan

    \noindent\rlap{\usebox{\dottedlines}}

    \needspace{\itemsize}
    \item Ava

    \noindent\rlap{\usebox{\dottedlines}}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```